# GStreamer: how to generate silence if audio is shorter than video

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm in a situation where I process video and audio streams simultaneously, but it happens that the audio stream is shorter. I need to insert silence buffers instead of just not playing anything in this case so that the streams end at the same timestamp. (The case when the video stream is shorter is already handled)

Is there some existing element I can use for this or should I write a new one or customize some other?

Thanks!

Comment: First: Why C and C++? Second, Stackoverflow is not a code-writing-service. Please show us some code you have done and where your problem is.

Comment: I am not asking to write the code for me, I am perfectly fine doing that myself. I am asking if anyone knows something that could save me some precious time. Because, honestly, you know how GStreamer documentation is. Ok, maybe a good regarding tags, will fix.

Comment: Have you tried considering element `appsrc` ? Could be useful in inserting buffers.

Comment: There is `audiorate` which does similar things. But since you want to do something based on lengths of other streams you probably will have to trick something in your application..

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated. You could use something like:

```
... ! audiodecoder ! adder name=mix ! ...
audiotestsrc wave=silence ! mix.
```

For this to work you need to configure the duration of the video on the audiotestsrc, e.g. query duration of video and then send a seek to the audiotestsrc.

Unfortunately I can't think of anything easier right now. If I may ask what is the problem with the audio stream to be slightly shorter?

Comment: Thanks, ensonic, that looks interesting. The problem is that I am implementing a playout application which needs to stitch several consecutive multimedia files together in an uninterrupted stream for broadcast. As far as I understand, the receiving end will not be happy if the stream has discontinuities. What do you think about the other comment that proposes to try `audiorate` to make the audio stream “perfect”?

Comment: If you stitch multiple streams, I'd just let adder with an audiotestsrc running for the whole time. AFAIK audiorate would not help to fix the length.

Comment: I have same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668287/gstreamer-end-of-stream but audio is stream. if i send `eos` to audioin - silence not added and pipe stopped