# Gstreamer end of stream

Tags: python, gstreamer

I have two streams. Video and audio. One of them can be empty, i.e. end-of-stream at start.
But

```
0:00:10.147044434 51257 0x563c0d51b060 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3384:gst_base_sink_default_event:<fsink> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:10.147150353 51257 0x563c0d51b060 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:3076:gst_qt_mux_start_file:<mux> Robust muxing requires reserved-moov-update-period to be set
0:00:10.148059000 51257 0x563c0d51b060 FIXME             aggregator gstaggregator.c:1323:gst_aggregator_aggregate_func:<mux> Subclass should call gst_aggregator_selected_samples() from its aggregate implementation.
0:00:10.148492779 51257 0x563c0d51b060 WARN                   qtmux gstqtmux.c:5010:gst_qt_mux_add_buffer:<mux> error: Buffer has no PTS.
0:00:10.149045344 51257 0x563c0d51b1e0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<videoin> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:10.149105380 51257 0x563c0d51b1e0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<videoin> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
0:00:10.149198331 51257 0x563c0d51b1e0 WARN                   queue gstqueue.c:990:gst_queue_handle_sink_event:<vq> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:10.149227154 51257 0x563c0d51b1e0 WARN                   queue gstqueue.c:990:gst_queue_handle_sink_event:<vq> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
```

Feeding video after audio eos makes no output. Pipe looks like

```
appsrc name=audioin | queue | capsfilter | alawdec | .mp4mux
appsrc name=videoin | queue | capsfilter | h264parse | .mp4mux
mp4mux | filesink
```

How make mux fail safe?

I added `adder` element and `audiotestsrc wave=silence` but then i send eos on audioin - videoin and silence stops

```
0:00:10.175976916 18730 0x55a12aedcf60 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<silence> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:10.176020798 18730 0x55a12aedcf60 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<silence> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
0:00:10.176242058 18730 0x55a12aedce40 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<videoin> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:10.176269841 18730 0x55a12aedce40 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3127:gst_base_src_loop:<videoin> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was muxer bug, `flvmux` works. Video without audio has no PTS.

Comment: but i need mp4mux)